# Heroku H12 Request Timeout Error when serving precompiled assets

Tags: heroku

I am running a rails application on Heroku. I've been getting H12 Request Timeout Errors every few hours as such:

```
heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/assets/application-c280172e4ef44cbe29d1fc72c6dfcd00.js" host=www.justvacay.com request_id=8e570b7c-0470-47b7-9f3b-41c1158b448d fwd="66.249.79.111" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=30005ms status=503 bytes=0
```

This started happening after I installed unicorn-worker-killer.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't process HTTP requests for over 30seconds, so if you are trying to host an application that does a heavy duty task (for instance, access a working API or something else that takes a long time) it is best to create worker dynos that can do the heavy coding in the background.

Here are the steps to do this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Another (potential) solution would be to go into the application that is taking a long time and create sessions within every function to avoid having heroku time running out. Here is an example on how to do this:

https://help.heroku.com/AXOSFIXN/why-am-i-getting-h12-request-timeout-errors-in-nodejs

This is not 100% guaranteed to work though.

Hope that this is helpful and good luck!